# How to get data in class A from class B in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, rxjs

Here I added two Classes and want to get data from one class to another class but I am getting errors like this "Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it."

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DataHtml from "../datahtml";


export default class AllData extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="row g-6 g-xl-9">
                <DataHtml />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


import React, { Component } from 'react';

class DataHtml extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            data: [ {"name": "demo","date": "02-02-2022"},{"name": "demo","date": "02-02-2022"}]        
            }
    }

    DataHtmlStructure = () => {
        this.state.data.map((data) => {
            return (
                <div className="col-md-6 col-xl-4 test-card">
                    <div className="card-body p-9 pt-4">
                        <div className="fs-3 fw-bolder text-dark mb-1">{data.name}</div>
                        <div className="fs-5 text-gray-600">
                            <i className="bi bi-calendar-date-fill"></i>{data.date}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        })
    }

    render() {
        return this.DataHtmlStructure;
    }
}
export default DataHtml;
```

Comment: Did you search all the results you get on this very site for that warning if you search for it? Please do that research first, and then tell us with an [edit] why those do not apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke your function in your render method.

```
    render() {
        return this.DataHtmlStructure();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Abe, It's removing the error message but still, I am not getting HTML structure from DataHtmlStructure().

Comment: You also have to add `return` before `this.state.data.map((data) => {`inside your `DataHtmlStructure` method.